# Make a WHERE clause affect a single column in a query

Tags: sql, postgresql

As the questions stated I am looking to make a WHERE clause affect a single column and am having issues. My query is as follows

```
Select exp, COUNT(grade), COUNT(exp)
FROM table
WHERE grade = 100
GROUP BY exp;
```

essentailly I want a output that groups by exp and gives a full count of everyone with that exp but in the second column shows only how many of those people got perfect scores. The problem is the current WHERE affects the COUNT(exp). Beginner to SQL so sorry if this is simple and thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You want conditional aggregation, which in Postgres uses `filter`:

```
SELECT exp, COUNT(*),
       COUNT(*) filter (where grade = 100)
FROM table 
GROUP BY exp;
```